# Perl 'if' statement

Tags: perl, if-statement

Right now, I have the following Perl code

```
my $tmpl1="download1_video.html"
 if $file->{file_name}=~/\.(avi|divx|mkv|flv|mp4|wmv)$/i;
$tmpl1||="download1.html";
```

so it's checking to see if the file is a video, and if so it directs it to the certain page. Although I'm just wondering how I can add another if statement in there to check if the extension is .mp3, and if so direct it to *download1_audio.html*.

Comment: btw, `my ... if ...;` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($file->{file_name} =~ /\.(avi|divx|mkv|flv|mp4|mp3|wmv)$/i )
{
    if ($1 eq "mp3")
    {
        # mp3 stuff
    }
    elsif ($1 eq "mp4")
    {
       # mp4 stuff
    }
    else
    {
       # all other file types
    }
}
else
{
    # It didn't match
}
```

A fancier way would be to create a hash keyed by your file types in advance with the info you needed for your next page; the filename I guess?

```
my %pageHash = ( "mp3" => "mp3Page.html", "divx" => "divxPage.html", ... );
...
$file->{file_name} =~ /\.(.*)$/i;
if (exists $pageHash{$1})
{
     $page = $pageHash{$1};
}
else
{
     # unknown file extension 
}
```

Comment: but wheres the video stuff happen in this case

Comment: Your test for "mp3" is always false.

Comment: Doh! Yeah, would help to have `mp3` in the pattern. Editing

Comment: @Belgin Fish - It's a simple if structure - if it matches at all the type (file extension) is captured in `$1`. You then see if it matches a specific thing. Every other file type would go to the `else { # other stuff here } `

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( $file->{file_name} =~  m/\.(avi|divx|mkv|flv|mp4|wmv)$/i ){
     ## Download video
}
elsif($file->{file_name} =~  m/\.(mp3)$/i){
     ## Download Audio
}
```

Is this what you needed ?

Comment: `elsif` is indeed better then querying the extensions twice but `.` should be replaced with `\.`

Comment: @Itamar: yeah right. I think while copy pasting the regex from the question, the escape operator missed out :P

Answer (score 1):

Having just been burnt by this, I must advise you against declaring a variable with a conditional modifier. If the condition does not hold true, it runs *no* part of the other clause, which means that you are *not* declaring `$tmpl1`, but since it's already passed strict, it allows you to assign to an undefined position in memory.

There is a safer way to do what your predecessor is doing here, that can yet illustrate a solution.

```
my $tmpl1
    = $file->{file_name} =~ /\.(avi|divx|mkv|flv|mp4|wmv)$/i 
        ? 'download1_video.html'
        : $file->{file_name} =~ m/\.mp3$/i
            ? 'download1_audio.html'
            : 'download1.html'
    ;
```

Thus,

1. `$tmpl1` is always declared
2. `$tmpl1` is always assigned a value

Comment: I would suggest following this advice when formatting ternaries. http://books.google.com/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&lpg=PP1&dq=perl%20best%20practices%20ternary&pg=PT55#v=onepage&q&f=false  The test/action table structure makes them much easier to read than the traditional cascade of choices.

Comment: @Schwern, I normally use table structure, but not when the condition is so long.

Comment: Make the condition shorter.  https://gist.github.com/1237023 A long condition is a readability red flag.

Comment: @Schwern, oh I agree, but there is an advantage in using somebody's own code when showing them a transformation.

Comment: Re *"assign to an undefined position in memory"*: Is that as scary as it sounds? Are we talking about undefined behaviour (like sending an email to the Moon)?